# Schengen visa expiry

Tags: visas, tourist-visas

Is it ok if my visa expires on the day I leave the Schengen area? That is, my visa expires 28 August and my flight out of the area is on that day.

Comment: It'll be okay as long as you actually get out of the Schengen area on that day.  What will you do if your flight is cancelled and the next flight out isn't until the following day?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You must leave the Schengen area before the end of the day of expiration of the visa. So if your visa expiration date is 28 August, you must leave before 23:59 on 28 August.